# rails how to get index on @items.zip(@user_items) do |item, ui,|

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on rails.

Hi this code <% @items.zip(@user_items).with_index do |item, ui, index| %>, I would like to add index number on this but I could not solve this.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

My a try, Syntax error.

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items).with_index do |item, ui, index| %>
  <td class="invert"><%= index %></td>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items).with_index do |item, ui, index| %>
<tr class="rem1">
    <td class="invert"><%= index %></td>
    <td class="invert-image" >
        <%= link_to image_tag(item.img.thumb.url || "sushi1.jpg", class: "img-responsive" ), item %>
    </td>

    <td class="invert">
    　　<div class="quantity"> 
        　<div class="quantity-select">                           
            　<div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
            　<div class="entry value" id="score-value"><%= ui.quantity %></div>
            　<div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
        　</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="invert"><%= link_to item.name, item %></td>
    <td class="invert">$ <%= link_to item.price, item %></td>
    <td class="invert">
            <%= link_to image_tag("close_1.png"), item_delete_in_baskets_path(item), method: :post, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class:"ml-2"%>
    </td>
</tr> 
<% end %>
```

baskets_contrller.rb

```
class BasketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show 
    # same as application controller
    
    basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    @user_items = basket.basket_items
    @basket_items = @user_items.select(:item_id)
    @items = Item.where(id: @basket_items)
    @total_price = basket.total_price
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just change `with_index` to `each_with_index`:

```rb
<% @items.zip(@user_items).each_with_index do |item, ui, index| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing an `each` so simply use `each_with_index` as eux already mentioned. Or, if you want to start iterating with a specified index you could use `each.with_index(initial_index)`.Ex:

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items).each.with_index(1) do |item, ui, index| %>
  index will start off from 1, then moves on to 2, 3...      
<% end %>
```